# Use leaflet to add information to my own database

Tags: database, leaflet

I would like to know how can i use Leaflet to send information to my database. the idea was to create a editor where i click add a marker add a few types of information and then send to my own database the information of the marker as is lat and log?

Thank you for all the help.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow.  please read this article before asking a question to make sure that you get a good answer http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: There should be no technical difficulty in doing what you describe. Then it depends on your skills and setup. If you are a beginner, look for tutorials on Internet for regular websites. Leaflet can be simply seen as a kind of form / input. Come with detailed code should you need any help in your programming.